# Jmeter - Response Code: 401 | Response Message: Session timeout cookie not set

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, session-cookies, adfs, blazemeter

I am using jmeter and in one of the GET and POST methods I am getting - **Response Code:401** | **Response Message: Session Time out cookie not set**.

1. I have set **Http Cookie Manager** as Global variable before the Thread Group.
2. ADFS login is passing and I am getting required cookies for - **Launch URL**, **Landing Page (after login)**, **Logout**.
3. In one of the POST API i get the following Request Cookie and Header:

   POST data:
   {}

   Cookie Data:
   TxxxAuth=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; TxxxAuth1=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; TxxxAuth2=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; 50FC05F7-187E-4603-99BA-3269EAE586C9=eyJTZXNzaW9uSWQiOiJhYjZjMTQyZC1mMWEyLTRmMDEtODc2ZC1hNzI2MDBjNTBmNDMiLCJUaW1lb3V0VGltZVV0YyI6IjAyLzI2LzIwMTcgMTI6Mjc6MjkiLCJUaW1lb3V0RHVyYXRpb24iOjMwLCJUZW5hbnRJZCI6ImI0NjI4YTBjLTlmMmMtNDRhYS1iMzE0LTdmZTY1YmU3MDg4YyIsIlBlcnNvbklkIjoiYjM3ODc0MGQtYWQwYy00YmIyLTg1NTQtYTcyMzAwNWQ0N2YzIiwiSXNFeHBpcmVkIjpmYWxzZX0%3d; 0B8A8B36-05A3-4359-BE72-49411DBED5B1="02/26/2017 11:57:28"; 16D5A74E-A74E-4AEB-A25A-28A48B88E090="02/26/2017 12:27:29"

   Request Headers:
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
   Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
   Origin: https://xxx-dev.com
   Referer: https://xxx-dev.com/abc/
   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
   Connection: keep-alive
   TokenHash: {"Salt":"CaSDwW5rZd5s9X4lPWkxpTQgrNgsq+f5PDIfwuDg+PJykjSIplEhEy5QJqGM6rxtwW5TkRopLwSK43jEr6w6og==","Hash":"A5BwLYxf0CoGfV1NDseSGp65MftAmFhRP7HYzLboTHA="}
   Content-Length: 2

Response from server:

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-02-26 06:57:28 EST
Load time: 3
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 3
Size in bytes: 274
Sent bytes:6096
Headers size in bytes: 274
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 401
Response message: Session timeout cookie not set

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Session timeout cookie not set
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity: true
Date: Sun, 26 Feb 2017 11:57:28 GMT
Content-Length: 0


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

When I checked in fiddler and Chrome Developer tool - this is the Request Message sent (it has passed in chrome developer tool):

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://xxx-dev.com
TokenHash: {"Salt":"kBa7ZWLbqOPbkYhsZSAcktsovgrhOxSPwLtA4NwnWKj1Pwoea98PdQHDN47AmRWJ4OZe2ct2AIjJ2lagkv2B2Q==","Hash":"JWVlp5S8qNsARDIhtYRwMJGRpmTrD+HzwaXlS2xLrto="}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: https://xxx-dev.com/abc/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: TxxxAuth=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; TxxxAuth1=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; TxxxAuth2=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; 50FC05F7-187E-4603-99BA-3269EAE586C9=eyJTZXNzaW9uSWQiOiI0OTVlZWY2Yy1lNzRjLTQ5ODctYTcyNy1hNzI2MDA4NzIyNDUiLCJUaW1lb3V0VGltZVV0YyI6IjAyLzI2LzIwMTcgMDg6NDI6MDEiLCJUaW1lb3V0RHVyYXRpb24iOjMwLCJUZW5hbnRJZCI6ImI0NjI4YTBjLTlmMmMtNDRhYS1iMzE0LTdmZTY1YmU3MDg4YyIsIlBlcnNvbklkIjoiYjM3ODc0MGQtYWQwYy00YmIyLTg1NTQtYTcyMzAwNWQ0N2YzIiwiSXNFeHBpcmVkIjpmYWxzZX0%3d; 0B8A8B36-05A3-4359-BE72-49411DBED5B1=02/26/2017 08:12:00; 16D5A74E-A74E-4AEB-A25A-28A48B88E090=02/26/2017 08:42:01
```

Question: Since it says **session time out cookie not set** is it due to the Quotes in jmeter response?

```
0B8A8B36-05A3-4359-BE72-49411DBED5B1="02/26/2017 11:47:08"; 16D5A74E-A74E-4AEB-A25A-28A48B88E090="02/26/2017 12:17:09"
```

Cos I dont see this in Chrome developer tool or in fiddler.

I tried to mitigate the issue by providing additional header for the sampler and passed the following parameters:

```
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Cookie  TxxxAuth=${COOKIE_TeleAuth}; TxxxAuth1=${COOKIE_TxxxAuth1}; TxxxAuth2=${COOKIE_TeleAuth2}; 50FC05F7-187E-4603-99BA-3269EAE586C9=${COOKIE_50FC05F7-187E-4603-99BA-3269EAE586C9}; 0B8A8B36-05A3-4359-BE72-49411DBED5B1=${COOKIE_0B8A8B36-05A3-4359-BE72-49411DBED5B1}; 16D5A74E-A74E-4AEB-A25A-28A48B88E090=${COOKIE_16D5A74E-A74E-4AEB-A25A-28A48B88E090}
handle-errors-globally  true
Host    xxx-dev.com
Origin  https://xxx-dev.com
Referer https://xxx-dev.com/Stratus/
```

But I do still find the quotes even after bypassing the global cookie manager.

is this cos of the quotes in the session time out variable in cookies or is it cos of something else? please help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with trial and error and believe it or not its very simple.

I did compose the API parameters (method, headers,cookies, payload) in fiddler and found that quotes is the issue which was causing the 401 error with Response Message: Session Time out cookie not set.

**Solution**: In the global **Http Cookie Manager** set the **Cookie Policy** to **Default** and **Implementation** in my case was **HC3CookieHandler**

This fixed the quotes issue in cookies.

Thanks.